# vhistory package: how to change the font size of the heading 'Revision History'

Tags: packages

I am using the `vhistory` package in latex, and I was wondering if there is any option to change the size of the automatic heading entitled ``Revision History'' (see picture) which is automatically created by this package.

[image]

Here my MWE

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{vhistory}

\begin{document}
    \begin{versionhistory}
    \vhEntry{0}{\today}{XY}{First release.}
    \end{versionhistory}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to disable the header using the `nochapter` package option, and write your own header manually with the desired size and style.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapter]{vhistory}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\textbf{Version History}
    \begin{versionhistory}
    \vhEntry{0}{\today}{XY}{First release.}
    \end{versionhistory}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use the header but redefine the header command. The `\vhhistoryname` macro is localized. Note that you can use this macro for the first approach as well.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{vhistory}
\makeatletter
\def \vh@chapter{%
  \markright{\vhhistoryname}%
  \noindent{\large\textit{\vhhistoryname}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{versionhistory}
    \vhEntry{0}{\today}{XY}{First release.}
    \end{versionhistory}
\end{document}
```

[image]